# CSS Column strange behaviour (offsetting items)

Tags: angularjs, css

I am displaying a number of tiles that vary slightly in height see below image and I thought that I had solved this issue without using masonry by using css columns.

Tiles:

[image: Tiles]

My code for this is :

```
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 4px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 4px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 4px;
```

Each tile has a `ng-click` that runs a function - passing the exercise object to the function.

**The column CSS is offsetting the tiles by one. For example if I was to click on `Tip Toe Line Walking` - it actually passed the object for Side `Step Across Beam` - they are all offset by 1 place in the grid.**

If I run the normal css then it functions perfectly. Why does the column css display correctly however pass the incorrect variable?

EDIT
This works fine in Safari on iPad.

Comment: Why do you mention angular - isn't this a pure css question?
Could you please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I mention angular incase there is a directive that is somehow causing the problem because the tiles are created using `ng-repeat`

Comment: Just a thought, but you can set the tiles to `display:table-cell` and they will render as the same height. I have done this before with dynamic content to avoid crazy JS calculations

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. With `display:table-cell` I am not getting a grid - just one row.